# Why is 'unharmed' put after the verb in this sentence

Tags: grammar

Sentence:

> People managed to get out of the building in the explosion **unharmed**.

**My question**: Why is *unharmed* put after the verb?

Is it a special adjective that I should remember?

If there is some grammar here, could you tell me about it?

Comment: Those people got out ***unharmed, uninjured, unhurt, unscathed,...*** What is it you don't understand about the cited usage?

Comment: Nothing special about the adjective. It's a kind of sentence where one or more people are  described as being in a particular state after doing something or having it done to them. _They escaped unharmed. He arrived exhausted. I was sent away still hungry_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Because I am not a native speaker so I have to learn grammar to use english and according to my grammar books ,Adjective have certain positions and it doesn't include that position above so I was just confused . Can I ask you a question : "How many positions of adjective do you know". Can you tell me or just give me a link so I can read about that. Thank you very much !

Comment: The adjective "unharmed" is here called a **predicative adjunct**: predicative because it refers to a predicand - "people"- and an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure, i.e. it's located in the verb phrase ("managed to get out of the building in the explosion unharmed") not in the subject noun phrase, which is just "people".

Answer (score 1):

[This comment](/q/545513/english-grammar-quetions-about-adjective#comment1340569_545513) from [BillJ](/users/141248/billj) appears to be an answer, so here it is as an answer:

> The adjective *unharmed* is here called a **predicative adjunct:** "predicative" because it refers to a predicand — *people* — and an "adjunct" because it's a modifier in clause structure, i.e. it's located in the verb phrase ("managed to get out of the building in the explosion unharmed") not in the subject noun phrase, which is just "people".

Comment: It's not obvious to me why the grammatical role of "unharmed" is any different to *People managed to get out of the building **early***. Or *People escaped unharmed, She survived unharmed, He arrived early*, come to that.

Comment: I think the problem is *"in the explosion"* - as an adverbial, explosions are instantaneous affairs and are not seen as having a duration. It could be part of NP *"the building in the explosion"* but that does not sound very idiomatic -the building that exploded.

Comment: "Early" does not describe the subject (it's not "early people"), and hence it's a temporal adjunct in clause structure, not a predicative one. "People escaped unharmed" / "She survived unharmed" have the same analysis as the OP's example. Optional predicatives like "unharmed" are adjuncts, so that the predicative/non-predicative contrast cuts across that between complements and adjuncts.